# How to prevent selection of the row while it is being handled?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have MySQL (InnoDB) table with the column `is_locked` which shows current state of the record (is it being handled by system now, or not).

On the other hand, I have many nodes that perform `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE is_locked = 0` and then handles got rows from this table.

In my code I do this:

1. System takes the row from DB (`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE is_locked = 0`)
2. System lockes the row by command `UPDATE table_name SET is_locked = 1 WHERE id = <id>`

Problem:
Nodes are working very fast, all of them may get the same row, before first of them will update the row and set `is_locked` to 1

I found out LOCKING of the tables, but I don't think it is the right way.
Can anybody tell me, how to handle such cases?

Comment: You can lock individual rows in InnoDB.

Comment: It's a fundamentally flawed idea to store the locking yourself.  What happens if you script crashes and burns and leaves that row locked.  It will be locked and you have no way to know if a process is using it or not.

Comment: >It's a fundamentally flawed idea to store the locking yourself. What happens if you script crashes and burns and leaves that row locked. It will be locked and you have no way to know if a process is using it or not. –

You are absolutely right, that's why I'm asking you here :)

Comment: At the very least a),limit your select and b) include `WHERE is_locked=0 and id = blah` in your update so only one attempt to update will succeed. Check the return value, if the update affected 0 rows your node didn't get that lock/shouldn't process. All this would be better done in a stored procedure that first updates one row, then returns that one row it updated, rather than select first, update later

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two things:

- Limit your select to one, as you're dealing with concurrency issues, it is better to take smaller "bites" with each iteration
- Use transactions, this allows you to start the transaction, get the record, lock it and then commit the transaction.  This will force mysql to enforce your concurrency locks.

Comment: Transactions didn't do the trick. I did commit after update, and all other nodes got previous result. Strange.

Comment: Can you show me how you're doing the transactions? Maybe include a gist/pastebin link to include the php as well.

Comment: I already used the solution above. First update the row, and then get it by ID. That's working perfectly. Thanks.